# "Attributes and objects cannot be resolved" - error

Tags: java

The following code is for reading or writing files with java, but:

Eclipse prints these errors:

- buffer_1 cannot be resolved to a variable
- file_reader cannot be resolved
- *also other attributes*...

what is wrong in this code here:

```
    //Class File_RW
    package R_2;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.lang.NullPointerException;

    public class File_RW {
        public File_RW() throws FileNotFoundException, NullPointerException {
            File file_to_read = new File("C:/myfiletoread.txt");
            FileReader file_reader = new FileReader(file_to_read);
            int nr_letters = (int)file_to_read.length()/Character.BYTES;
            char buffer_1[] = new char[nr_letters];
        }
        public void read() {
            file_reader.read(buffer_1, 0, nr_letters);
        }
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(buffer_1);
        }
            public void close() {
                    file_reader.close();
            }
            public File get_file_to_read() {
                    return file_to_read;
            }
            public int get_nr_letters() {
                    return nr_letters;
            }
            public char[] get_buffer_1() {
                    return buffer_1;
            }
            //...
    }

    //main method @ class Start:

    package R_2;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.lang.NullPointerException;

    public class Start {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                File_RW file = null;
            try {
                file = new File_RW();
            } catch (NullPointerException e_1) {
                System.out.println("File not found.");
            }
                    //...
        }
    }
```

I can't find any mistake. I have also tried to include a `try catch` statement into the constructor of the class "File_RW", but the error messages were the same.

Comment: You need to _declare_ your class members (e.g. `file_reader`, etc) in your class, then _initialize_ them in constructor.

Comment: If you're getting an error, you probably made a mistake.

Comment: Another subtle hint: you do not need to import any class form that lives in the java.lang package (such as NullPointerException)! And then: cursing doesn't help. What is kinda really wrong here is that you first wrote 50+ lines of code before you run the compiler the first time. Or that you keep ignoring the error messages eclipse is giving you as soon as you started to mess up your code!

Comment: And just for the record: I very much think that my answer is correct, and that you don't need to wait for another one ;-) ... and as I am just a few points away from hitting the daily limit ... a quick accept would be extremely helpful to me ;-) but of course, that is up to you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are **errors** in your code - which are of really **basic** nature: you are declaring **variables** instead of **fields**. 
Meaning: you have them in the constructor, but they need to go one layer up! When you declare an entity within a constructor or method, then it is a *variable* that only exists within that constructor/method.

If you want that multiple methods can make use of that entity, it needs to be a **field**, declared in the scope of the enclosing class, like:

```
class FileRW {
  private File fileToRead = new File...
  ...
```

and then you can use your **fields** within all your methods! Please note: you can do the actual setup within your constructor:

```
class FileRW {
  private File fileToRead;

  public FileRW() {
    fileToRead = ..
```

but you don't have to.

Finally: please read about java language conventions. You avoid using "_" within names (just for SOME_CONSTANT)!

Answer (score 0):

javacode already running...thx
same program edited with c++ in visual Studio express...
visit the stackoverflow entry link:
[c++ file read write-error: Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime libr..debug Assertion failed, expr. stream.valid()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794904/c-file-read-write-error-microsoft-visual-c-runtime-libr-debug-assertion-fa)

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?